# How do I resolve a TLS Error associated with smtpd?

Tags: postfix, ssl, smtp, django

I found the following in the logs:

```
sssd_kcm[425899]: Starting up
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: connect from unknown[::1]
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/run/spamass-milter/spamass-milter.sock: No such file or directory
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[::1]
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: unknown[::1]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:HIGH:MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client hello
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server hello
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write certificate
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write finished
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL3 alert read:fatal:bad certificate
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept:error in error
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: SSL_accept error from unknown[::1]: -1
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 42:
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[::1]
postfix/submission/smtpd[425910]: disconnect from unknown[::1] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
```

Those two lines show up any time a user presses a "Password reset" button on a User authentication form.  This is happening on all Django projects hosted on a VPS at the moment. Consequently, the server does not send the email that initiates the reset. Instead, users see "Server Error (500)" on the browser.  This phenomenon is new. The pages were working months before.

The log entries seem to suggest that the certificates are bad.  I have renewed all certs on that server in an attempt to resolve the issue but the it persists.  Note that mail submission via remote and local clients are working perfectly.

I would appreciate guidance on how to remedy the situation.

**# postconf | grep cert | grep smtp**

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtp_tls_cert_file =
smtp_tls_dcert_file =
smtp_tls_dkey_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
smtp_tls_eccert_file =
smtp_tls_eckey_file = $smtp_tls_eccert_file
smtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match =
smtp_tls_key_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop, dot-nexthop
smtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 9
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dcert_file =
smtpd_tls_dkey_file = $smtpd_tls_dcert_file
smtpd_tls_eccert_file =
smtpd_tls_eckey_file = $smtpd_tls_eccert_file
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = no
tlsproxy_client_cert_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
tlsproxy_client_dcert_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
tlsproxy_client_eccert_file = $smtp_tls_eccert_file
tlsproxy_client_scert_verifydepth = $smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth
tlsproxy_tls_ask_ccert = $smtpd_tls_ask_ccert
tlsproxy_tls_ccert_verifydepth = $smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth
tlsproxy_tls_cert_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
tlsproxy_tls_dcert_file = $smtpd_tls_dcert_file
tlsproxy_tls_eccert_file = $smtpd_tls_eccert_file
tlsproxy_tls_req_ccert = $smtpd_tls_req_ccert
```

Comment: Getting a alert bad certificate means that the peer (likely the client submitting the mail) cannot verify the certificate you've provided. This might be a wrong configuration in your server regarding the certificate (like wrong certificate or missing intermediates) or it might be that the client has not the necessary trust anchors to verify your certificate. More help might be provided if more details are known, i.e. about the client configuration, your server configuration, the certificates used. If the phenomenon is new then you might start thinking about what has changed in configuration.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Is it possible that using one cert for more than one subdomains is the culprit?  In which case, it is better to have separate certs for each subdomain. The thing is, the mails are originating from the same machine ("localhost"). Which aspects of the config are relevant for troubleshooting?

Comment: It does not matter if you have one certificate for all domains or different certificates for each domain. What matters to check are a) how you've configured the certificate files b) the actual content of the files you've configured (i.e. which certificates are inside) c) which CA the client trusts.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks for the clarification. The SSL certs are from Letsencrypt. Which  postfix keyword=value assignments would help your analysis? postconf outputs a lot.  I have modified the post to include some that may be relevant

Comment: These error messages are usually hard to understand as similar sounding errors can mean quite different things. In this case, I believe the issue is with the client certificate not the server certificate. IE the server receiving the mail is rejecting the client certificate of the sending agent. As Steffen Ullrich says, this may be a problem with not providing necessary intermediaries or the server not trusting the CA that signed the client certificate.  You may get more meaningful error message if you have access to the receiving server's logs.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, I have updated log section of the post above to loglevel=2.  Django-allauth is trying to send a password reset email via postfix. Django and postfix are on the same machine.  Email submissions from external clients still work when using STARTTLS.  If Django is experiencing an error, then the issue is between django and postfix. Perhaps more insight on how django handles certs will help.

Answer (score 0):

**Short version:**
I have been silly.

**Long Version:**
The source of the issue was right under my nose. I had the following assignment in the Django project/settings.py files:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
```

For development purposes, that is understandable. I forgot to adapt the value to the production environment. Strangely, that worked for a while. I did not realize that the assignment was the cause of the failing TLS handshakes until I ran the following script within a relevant Django shell:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    "Test Subject",
    "Mr Elephant is tusking the microphone",
    "me@email.com",
    ["there@email.com"],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

**The output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/srv/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/project/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in open
    self.connection.starttls(context=self.ssl_context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 790, in starttls
    self.sock = context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'localhost'. (_ssl.c:1006)
```

The last line did it for me. Sure enough, that triggered the exact entries in the logs. My apologies!

**The fix:**

```
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.servername.com"
```